# If a witness claims his signature was taken on blank paper and then statements were written would that become null and void?

Tags: india, witnesses, indian-penal-code, statement

This is in relation to the [Aryan Khan's Case](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/entertainment/hindi/bollywood/news/aryan-case-live-ncb-sameer-wankhede-move-special-court-against-extortion-allegations/liveblog/87247422.cms) in which one of the witness claims his signature was taken on a blank paper and he was not aware of what was going to be written on it. He signed it because he was at the NCB office and senior official asked him to do so saying nothing will happen.

This seems like a joke that a person will sign on blank paper, nevertheless now that he is making U turn from the statement. Will that statement be admissible in the court of law or it will be null and void?

Are witnesses allowed to back away from signed statement?

Comment: NCB=Narcotics Control Bureau (a law enforcement agency in India).

Answer (score 2):

> Are witnesses allowed to back away from signed statement?

In substance, the person whose signature was used is alleging forgery and evidence falsification in a criminal case, presumably by corrupt law enforcement officials.

This witness is entitled to dispute the evidence on that grounds in a criminal prosecution, or if he is called upon to be a witness in another case. Whether the finder of fact in that case will believe his claim that the evidence was forged is another question, but he can try to establish this claim.

> then statements were written would that become null and void?

Basically, although this is a somewhat weird way to express the idea. The claim is that he never made the statements in the first place. Somebody made those statements (perhaps a corrupt law enforcement officer) and the statements don't cease to exist because they may have been forged. But if he establishes that the statements were forged than they aren't his statements and there is nothing for him to make "null and void."